# How to create vagrant box for already created VirtualBox windows machine (.vbox file)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I have already set-up Oracle VM for few windows OS versions.
Now i want to handle the deployments , configuration of those vboxes using vagrant.
Vagrant uses Box to handle the functions supported by vagrant commands.
Is there way to convert existing vboxes to Vagrant Box?
I tried using Vagrant package command but its giving error "`VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR`".
Just wanted to check if vagrant package command is only way to convert existing VM machines to vagrant boxes or are there other ways ?

Answer (score 1):

So finally i found solution to create box, by hitting here and there.
below is what i did :

a. Export Appliance for Windows GUEST OS 
In Virtual Box GUI, Click file >> export appliance >> select Guest OS which is already set-up in virtual Box for which .box file needs to be created

This will create .ova file from .vbox files

b. Once .ova file is create, we need to convert it in .box file using below command

Vagrant package --base Window10Pro --output Window10Pro.box  (my case was Windows10 )

This will take sometime but will eventually generate your .box file !